# kiB memory of physical ram (linux)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, memory-usage

How can I find amount of physical memory on linux.

Background: I want to be sure, that the sum of all kvm machines, don't use more RAM than available.

I can find the kiB sum like this:

```
for dom in $(virsh list --all --name); do virsh dumpxml $dom | sed -nre 's/^.*>([0-9]*)<.currentMemory.*$/\1/p' ; done| awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

But the values of /proc/meminfo are in kB not kiB....

Comment: I have a feeling the kB in meminfo *are* kiB, but if not, just multiply by 1.024.

Comment: @phoebus feelings are good and numbers, too. But feelings about numbers are ... unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Virsh has the `dommemstat` for every domain and is easier to be filtered out.

```
for meminfo in $(virsh list | awk 'NR > 1 {print $2}'); 
  do 
   virsh dommemstat "$meminfo"
  done | awk '/actual/{s+=$2}END{print s}'
```

Once you've done that, you can get the Nodes' total memory using:

```
virsh nodememstats | awk -F: '/total/{print +$2}'
```

Compare the two values and take the required action,